# Paypal Sandbox accounts not crediting seller account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have the sandbox running for Express Checkout. When I do a test payment using the Seller account in my sandbox, everything works, the payment is successful and the Buyer account gets the amount of the purchase deducted from it. But the seller account never gets any money in it.

I read somewhere that to activate the seller account you have to accept a billing agreement, but I don't know if that is valid for ExpressCheckout and I can't find it anyway.

I checked the username, password and signature and they are all correct.

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Can you please include a copy of all your relevant API call(s), minus credentials?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just started working on this again. I found out that the payment was set to pending because I was receiving payment in a foreign currency for which I didn't hold a balance. There is some way to automatically receive that, but i didn't know how to set it up in the sandbox. So i changed payment type to dollars and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comment above, the problem was that the currency type wasn't set to US Dollars. My sandbox account was set up in dollars to it couldn't receive anything else and the payment was set to pending for the reason of 'multi-currency'.